# Docker is always show "Docker Engine starting..."

Tags: docker, windows-10

Hello I got new existing projects and using docker.
The problem is my docker desktop app always in `Docker Engine starting...`, but in my icon it's already show `Docker Desktop is running`.

running on windows 10

[image: my docker app]

[image: my status at his icon]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just close docker desktop app and then open it up again, it will run normally again

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue running Docker Desktop 3.2.2.

Fixed by downloading Docker Desktop 3.3.0 (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the following method works:

1. open cmd as admin
2. enter **net stop winnat**
3. start or restart docker desktop
4. enter **net start winnat**

Answer (score 0):

Suddennly i opened my laptop and started Docker, it was displaying only "Docker desktop starting" and stuck here for long time. I tried to delete settings.json(auto created on starting docker again) at `\AppData\Roaming\Docker`
but nothing worked.
So, i simply **restarted my laptop** undoing all changes, and this time after few mins  Docker desktop started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When I check, I was using the latest version so downgrade the Desktop version 4 to version 3.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/previous-versions/3.x-windows/

summary - Try with a different version other than the latest one.

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

version 4.16.2 must be updated immediately to 4.16.3
open update to latest window and read the update cause:
Fixed Docker Desktop failing to start...

It couldn't be updated, so uninstall and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution on Windows 11 was to restart. Windows then installed some (Windows) updates which apparently were still missing, even though it did **not** show them when selecting restart via the start menu.

Usually - when updates still have to be installed - the text says "Update and restart", but in my case it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue for some reason when I have installed Ubuntu in my Windows machine after I have installed Docker Desktop. I have managed to fix the issue by following the steps below:

First, I have uninstalled the Docker and then restarted my computer.

Opened a Powershell terminal with administration rights to install the Ubuntu distro using the command `wsl --install -d Ubuntu`

Finally, installed [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/) from the website.

I always make sure that I start the Docker Desktop with administration rights.

Original [solution](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-stuck-on-starting/125351/3).

Comment: if i had already installed ubuntu distro, then what should i do ? how to uninstall it or what are the exact steps?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.

Run the following two lines of commands inside PowerShell.
First Exit docker hub desktop, then run these commands in PowerShell:

```shell
wsl --unregister docker-desktop
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
```

**Note**: It should be noted that this removes all docker containers and data. (WLS: Unregisters the distribution and deletes the root filesystem.)

Comment: I would suggest, move the note up, BEFORE the command. May people try it, and read later, ups your data has been gone.

Answer (score -3):

Rebooting fixed the issue for me.