# Docker desktop is stuck on "Docker Desktop starting..." on Windows 10

Tags: docker

**I've tried**

- Uninstall Docker
- Restart machine
- Installed a linux WLS distro: wsl --install -d Ubuntu
- Installed Docker again

Comment: you may try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72315945/1429367 (but be careful, these actions may be destructive!)

Comment: Did you solve the issue?